# How to receive a notification on finish of an asynchronous task

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I have NSOperationQueue with 3 NSInvocationOperation in a prepareForSegue callback and I need after finishing all async tasks move to another view controller.
How can I be notified about finishing all async tasks and only after this move to another screen?

I tried this without success:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

});
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that I not understand something :

```
-(void)initPurchase{

    [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

    NSInvocationOperation *downloadImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[BSImageDownloader getInstance] selector:@selector(downloadImageSync:) object:@"http://.........jpg"];


    NSInvocationOperation *createImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[BSImageCreator getInstance] selector:@selector(createImage:) object:@"dsadsadsa"];


    NSInvocationOperation *saveImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[BSImageSaver getInstance] selector:@selector(saveImageAsPng:) object:[BSSharedObject getInstance].createdImage];

    [createImageOperation addDependency:downloadImageOperation];
    [saveImageOperation addDependency:createImageOperation];


    [operationQueue addOperation:downloadImageOperation];
    [operationQueue addOperation:createImageOperation];
    [operationQueue addOperation:saveImageOperation];


}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    [[BSPopupManager getInstance]showWaitingPopup];


    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
                         ^{
                             Purchase *purchase = [[Purchase alloc] init];
                             [purchase initPurchase];
                         });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[BSPopupManager getInstance] closeWaitingPopup];
        BSPurchaseViewController *purchaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        purchaseViewController.pngImage = [BSSharedObject getInstance].createdImage;


 NSLog(@"2");
    });

    dispatch_release(group);

}
}
```

I still get NSLog(@"2"); earlier than I save image in 3rd NSInvocationOperation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dispatch_group_async()` function if you intend to use GCD to perform your asynchronous tasks: [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
^{
     //Code here is executed asynchronously
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{
   //Do something when async has completed
   //Note: You are not required to use the main 
   //queue if you aren't performing any UI work.
});

dispatch_release(group);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a fourth operation dependent on the first three that posts a NSNotification on the main thread. Something like

```
NSOperation * completionOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MyOperationsCompletedNotification object:... userInfo:nil];
  });
}];
[completionOp addDependency:op1];
[completionOp addDependency:op2];
[completionOp addDependency:op3];
[opQueue addOperation:op1];
[opQueue addOperation:op2];
[opQueue addOperation:op3];
[opQueue addOperation:completionOp];
```

I've left a `...` in the code because you might want to fill in the object field with something other than nil (but it should not be a UIKit class except those that are documented to be threadsafe).

Alternatively, each operation could return its results via a `dispatch_async()` or `-performSelectorOnMainThread:`, but again, it is unwise to reference an instance of a thread-unsafe UIKit class in a block (or as the receiver or object of a `-performSelectorOnMainThread:`).

There many ways to do this which are specifically mentioned as being thread-unsafe in the GameKit examples — in particular, anything which might end up calling `-release` on a UIView or UIViewController is dangerous, because that can cause `-dealloc` to be called on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using GCD **dispatch_group** in **Swift 3+**. You can get notified when all tasks are finished.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    run(after: 6) {
      print(" 6 seconds")
      group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    run(after: 4) {
      print(" 4 seconds")
      group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    run(after: 2) {
      print(" 2 seconds")
      group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    run(after: 1) {
      print(" 1 second")
      group.leave()
    }


    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
      print("All async calls completed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use key-value observing to watch the `isFinished` property of your `saveImageOperation`.